# как в python поймать сигнал kill -9 и выполнить функцию?

Tags: python, signal

Можно ли поймать сигнал `kill -9` и при его получении сначала вызвать функцию?

```
import os
import sys
import signal

def sig_handler(signall, frame, path):
        os.remove(path)
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: У меня он удалил файл path! Ловит!

Comment: а как вызвать функцию?

Comment: ```sig_handler ('kill-9','sd','users.txt')```

Comment: а разве не дложно быть чтото вроде 'signal.signal(signal.SIGKILL, sig_handler)' ? я не совсем понимаю синтаксис как подпихнуть path

Comment: так и не должно быть

Comment: а можно код целиком в ответ положить?

Comment: Никак. SIGKILL не ловится

Comment: да я понял про sigkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо alvanf за подсказку, я вроде придумал как запихнуть path.

```
import os
import sys
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM
from functools import partial
from time import sleep

def sig_handler(signall, frame, path):
    os.remove(path)
    sys.exit(0)


signal(SIGINT, partial(sig_handler,'/any/path/to/file'))
signal(SIGTERM, partial(sig_handler,'/any/path/to/file'))


sleep(100) ##чтобы отловить и убить через kill или ctrl+c
```

Answer (score 1):

Поймать сигнал 9 невозможно, на то он и kill, принудительное и незамедлительное завершение процесса. Но можно поймать сигнал 2 (interrupt, вызывается командой Ctrl+C) или 15 (terminate, graceful kill, из консоли `kill <pid>` без -9), для этого нужно просто зарегистрировать Ваш функцию:

```py
import signal
import time

# Первым аргументом будет число – код сигнала
# Вторым аргументом идёт фрейм, о них читайте в документации
def fun(signum, frame):
    print(signum, frame)

# Подписываемся на обработку конкретных сигналов:
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, fun)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, fun)

# Чтобы было, что убивать:
while True:
    print(int(time.time()) % 1000)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: а как можно добавить 'path'  в  'fun'  ? т.е. 'def fun(signum, frame, path):'

Comment: @Андрей А что за путь-то? Если очень хочется иметь третий аргумент, то поставьте ему стандартное значение, вроде `path=None`, но учтите, что `signal.signal` ничего туда ставить не будет. Если просто нужен  путь до какого-то файла или директории, то вычисляйте его самостоятельно, можно использовать тот же `frame`.